# Question on ox-odt : How to export special block as a two column section?

Tags: org-mode, org-export, odt

What I want to do is implement a special block, say, "Sect2", in an org file

```
#+attr_odt: :style Sect_2
#+begin_sect2
* heading 1
** subheading 1
* heading 2
#+end_sect2
```

"Sect_2" is a style defined in the template.

```
<style:style style:name="Sect2" style:family="section">
  <style:section-properties text:dont-balance-text-columns="false" style:editable="false">
    <style:columns fo:column-count="2" fo:column-gap="0in">
      <style:column style:rel-width="4986*" fo:start-indent="0in" fo:end-indent="0in"/>
      <style:column style:rel-width="4986*" fo:start-indent="0in" fo:end-indent="0in"/>
    </style:columns>
  </style:section-properties>
</style:style>
```

and the special block is translated according to the following template in the
final odt file. The name of the traslated block should increase automatically,
like "Sect_2_1", "Sect_2_2".

```
<text:section text:style-name="Sect_2" text:name="Sect_2_1">
[content]
<text:section>
```

Can anyone give me some tips on how to do this?